# Disable visual effects: Call to SystemParamtersInfo shows no effect

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, visual-effects

I am trying to disable all the visual effects within a Windows Server 2012 R2 remote desktop session. This is normally getting done via System => Advanced system settings => Performance "Settings" and apply the "adjust for best performance" preset.

As there are no group-policy settings nor registry values that can be set I stumbled of SystemParamtersInfo function. Unfortunately it has absolutly no effect on the RDP session I am testing it in.

I am no good programmer and this is what I knit together, with MSDN and google's help.

```
namespace SetVisualEffects
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

    public class SetVisualEffects
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, bool pvParam, uint fWinIni); 

        private static UInt32 SPI_SETUIEFFECTS = 0x103F;
        private static UInt32 SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING = 0x004b;
        private static UInt32 SPI_SETDROPSHADOW = 0x1025; 

        public static void Main()
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDROPSHADOW, 0, false, 0); 
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, false, 0);
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, false, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

And my similar approach using C++, unfortunately with the same outcome.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")    

int main()  
{
    // Disables all UI effects.
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Animate controls and elements inside windows"

    // Disables "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing"

    // Disables "Animations in the taskbar"

    // Disables "Enable Peek"

    // Disables "Fade or slide menus into view"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMENUANIMATION, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMENUFADE, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Fade or slide ToolTips into view"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETTOOLTIPFADE, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Fade out menu items after clicking"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSELECTIONFADE, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Save taskbar thumbnail previews"

    // Disables "Show shadows under mouse pointer"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Show shadows under windows"

    // Disables "Show thumbnails instead of icons"

    // Disables "Show translucent selection rectangle"

    // Disables "Show window contents while dragging"

    // Disables "Slide open combo boxes"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCOMBOBOXANIMATION, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Smooth edges of screen fonts"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Smooth-scroll list boxes"
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETLISTBOXSMOOTHSCROLLING, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    // Disables "Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop" 
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDROPSHADOW, 0, FALSE, SPIF_SENDCHANGE); 

    return 0; 
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `SystemParametersInfo` returns whether it succeeds or not which allows you to check for which error occurred.  I'd start with that, since right now you have no idea if anything is working or not.

Comment: Ignoring the result of `SystemParametersInfo` is like putting a `try`...`catch` block around a function call, without anything in the `catch` part of it. If something goes wrong, the function already tells you about it. What is it telling you?

Comment: Referencing my C# approach the call to `bool ret = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, false, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);` returns "True" - so the call succeeds, however no change on the visual effects.

Comment: Well it seems to take effect, at least mouse cursor shadow is disabled. However I can still see the content when dragging a window for example, so not all effects are disabled...

Comment: Lots of settings will only be applied to the windows of your program, not to every window on the desktop.  The applet does a great deal more, poking mysterious registry keys for example.  Undocumented, you see can some of it with SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: It seems I had wrong understanding of the whole thing... rather than coding a tool and binding it to a group-policy object, it's a lot easier to simply configure a remote desktop client's performance options. Even though we can't control e.g "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing" via RDP.

Comment: Well, there are actually  group-policy settings that control how DWM uses animations: `User Configuration => Policies => Administrative Templates => Windows Components => Desktop Window Manager => Do not allow window animations`